# Undesirable duplicate content with double foreach in blade

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

how can I make sure I use more foreach in my blade, without the content repeating more than once?

```
    $review = Review::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(9);
    $info_games = array();
    $games = array();
    foreach ($review as $value) {
        $info_games[]   =   InfoGames::where('id_game', $value->id_game)->first();
        $games[]    =   Games::where('id', $value->id_game)->first();
    }
    return view('front.pages.review.list', compact('review','info_games','games'));
```

and my blade:

```
@foreach ($review as $value)
@foreach ($info_games as $info_game)
    <div>
      <img src="https://gamelite.net/{{$info_game->image}}">
      <p>{!! str_limit($value->body, 150)  !!}</p>
    </div>
@endforeach
@endforeach
{!! $review->render() !!}
```

Comment: You need to look at the documentation again, see [relationships in eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships). Your code above will generate so many selects that If I was the computer running this I would purposely crash myself.

Comment: use relationship with eager load https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

use array_filter($array) . It will return unique .
in your case

```
$info_games = array_filter($info_games);
```